# Why async requests should be made in componentDidMount instead of getInitialState in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[This](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) page of React's docs shows that async requested data should be consumed in the `componentDidMount` event, while `getInitialState` initialize the state object to a default *empty* state.

Is there a reason for that? Maybe getInitialState is not expected to do this or has a different purpose? Is it due to some internal logic of the library?

*Note to moderators and answerers: this isn't an opinion-based question: if a reason exists, that would be the answer, however, a good, correct answer to my question could be as well "No, there isn't any particular reason, do whatever you feel better"*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getInitialState` should be a pure function of props (though they often aren't used).  In other words, with the same props getInitialState should return the same data.

`componentDidMount` is allowed to have dynamic behavior, and cause side effects such as dom manipulation and ajax requests (that's the main intention of it).

A common way to handle this is with an early return of either an empty div, loading message, `<div>Loading</div>`), or loading indicator (e.g. [spinkit](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/)).

On first render the spinner will be shown, and then eventually state is updated with data and the main part of render can be run.

```js
render: function(){
   // while loading
   if (!this.state.data){
     return <div className="spinner"></div>
   }

   // loaded, you can use this.state.data here
   return <div>...</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If in getInitialState I fetch the state of the component asynchronously using `props` as arguments for my request (for example, I have to fetch data from a known `id`), isn't it a "pure" function anyway?

Comment: If you do an ajax call on the parent and pass the state as props to the children, that would be fine. Or just do it in componentDidMount

Comment: AJAX is a side effect.  Pure functions don't have side effects.  Basically, if React decided to call getInitialState 100 times where it currently calls it one time, there should be no observable difference.  One hundred ajax requests would definitely be an observable difference.  This is why it's not a pure function.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't want to do this because your component will be waiting on the async request and it won't be able to mount until it's finished. If you have html with a couple state variables, let react render first instead of making it wait. I know this is an opinion but it's also a separation of concerns thing as well.