# Flux and React: how show a loading indicator when the requests from my app are made? The good, the bad and the ugly try

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'm trying to figure out the best way to hide/show the loading indicator when I'm doing a request.

I have a:

- **LoadingAction** to emmit an event to show/hide the loading indicator.
- **LoadingStore** to hold the loading information (show/hide).
- **loading.jsx**: the loading indicator component.

I tried different things to do that in the "flux way":

- **good**: call a `LoadingAction.showLoading()` before the request and `LoadingAction.hideLoading()` when the response arrives.
- **bad**: call a `LoadingAction.showLoading()` in each view that call an action (that made a request) and `LoadingAction.hideLoading()` when my callback is called from the Store.
- **ugly**: I tried to change the `LoadingStore` directly with a `setter` method (what is not the right solution...) when I made the request and receive the response.

But, except for the last try (the "ugly"), I always receive the error `dispatch in the middle of a dispatch`.

I'm aware that what this means but I can't think in another strategy.

I don't want to use `setTimeout` function to resolve this problem. This is not the right solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, we end up with the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615307/why-async-requests-should-be-made-in-componentdidmount-instead-of-getinitialstat/26618216#26618216). The approach was very different than my original idea: each component take cares about the loading, like this:

```
render: function(){
   // while loading
   if (!this.state.data){
     return <Loader/>
   }

   // loaded, you can use this.state.data here
   return <div>...</div>
}
```

But, we have problems when an API return an error. How the component can remove the `<Loader />` in this case?

Well, each component with  need to register and listen (we use Flux) the dispatch from our promise based HTTP client (Axios). Like this:

```
        componentDidMount: function(){
            LoaderStore.addChangeListenerEsconderLoading(this.stopLoading);
        },

        componentWillUnmount:function(){
            LoaderStore.removeChangeListenerEsconderLoading(this.stopLoading);
        },
```

And this (using Axios):

```
request(options)
  .then(function(response){
    success && success(response.data);
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
     LoaderAction.hideLoading();
  }
```